# Run task after Dropbox finished sync

Tags: sync, dropbox

To make matters easier for users I have made a system where they edit markdown files in dropbox which are synced to server after.

On server I am running a headless Dropbox daemon and made a rake task that imports pages form Dropbox folder.

Is there a way to run the task every time Dropbox sync finished? As of now I am thinking of keeping some invisible `.timestamp` file that will be checked vs folder date.

Comment: No way that I can find. You can check the nautilus-dropbox source (https://github.com/dropbox/nautilus-dropbox/blob/master/src/nautilus-dropbox-hooks.c), this is the official Nautilus integration tool from dropbox, so if there is a way it's likely there.